# How to compile python into an executable file?

Tags: python, compilation, debian

I'd like to know how to compile a .py file into an executable file.
I know that python is an interpreted language but i need to make an executable for a machine where i can't install a python interpreter so i'd like to compile it into an executable.
So i wonder if there could be a command line to make it (i traditionaly use Makefile for my programming project).

Thank you for reading

Comment: installing a *python interpreter* is equally complicated as installing any other program, including yours; so if you can install your exectable, you can also install python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PyInstaller - multiplatform](http://www.pyinstaller.org/)
[py2app - for Mac OS](http://pythonhosted.org/py2app/)
[Py2Exe - Windows](http://www.py2exe.org/)

Answer (score 2):

[cx-freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) this is also multiplateform